# AngularJS - nested forEach to iterate Json

Tags: json, angularjs, loops, foreach

I am trying to print out all the names and books of all of the series. So I use 2 `forEach` loops but the book info shows up on the console as undefined. Would you please tell me how to fix it?

Data:

```
var data = {
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "Spectrum Series",
            "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
            "book": [
                {
                    "name": "White Curse",
                    "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
                    "image": "book1"                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "Blue Fox",
                    "bookid": "BlueFox",
                    "image": "book2"                   
                }
            ]
        }

    … other series
 ]
};
```

Angular loops:

```
    $scope.serieslist = data.records;
   angular.forEach($scope.serieslist, function(series){
       console.log(series.name);
       angular.forEach(series, function(book){
           console.log(book.name);
       });         
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.forEach(series, function(book){`

must be

`angular.forEach(series.book, function(book){`